# SAP DI API update OBTW location field

Tags: c#, sap-business-one-di-api

Hi I'm trying to update the location of the `OBTW` table using the DI API of SAP Business One. It's really hard to find any examples on how to do this and I could only find a function to get to the `OBTN` table here: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/13/sample-code-to-update-existing-item-batches-properties-via-di-api/

Now I don't know what class should I use to access the `OBTW` table using the `ItemCode` and the `BatchCode`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the DI API Reference, there is no .Location or similar property that you can set. So it's not possible via DI API to change this value.

I'm using SAP Business One DI API 9.2 - Objects Reference (9.20.150) - BatchNumberDetail Object Members.